# Saving a file with a custom extension

Tags: c++, linux, qt, save, file-extension

I have a program I wrote in Windows with this piece of code that works on Windows, but when compiled in linux, the saved file doesn't have the .l2p extension.

```
void MainWindow::on_saveButton_clicked()
 {
     QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
         tr("Salvesta Projekt"), "",
         tr("Latid Pindalaks (*.l2p)"));

     if (fileName.isEmpty())
         return;
     ...
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is the final result that you get ?

Comment: It shows the saving dialog and it all seems fine, but the file it has saved has no extension.

Comment: The behaviour you want to force is exactly what I hate(d) about windows applications. File name extensions should be up to the user to use or not (they are part of the file name, which is chosen by the user). You could let the user choose between "Latid Pindalaks (\*.l2p)" and "All files (\*)" and only force the extension if he selected the first one. But I'm not sure if Qt provides you the info about which one has been selected in the combo box of the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file name doesn't have the extension you need, just add it:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
    tr("Salvesta Projekt"), "",
    tr("Latid Pindalaks (*.l2p)"));

if (fileName.isEmpty())
    return;

if (!fileName.endsWith(".l2p"))
    fileName += ".l2p";
```